# "Syntax error in insert into statement" when inserting image into Access table

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, ms-access

I am trying to insert text and images into a table. Here is my code:

```
conn.Open();
cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO users (user_name,father_name,phone,email,cnic,address,user_type,workshop,department,designation,emergency_no,image) values(@user_name,@father_name,@phone,@email,@cnic,@address,@user_type,@workshop,@department,@designation,@emergency_no,@image);";
//using MemoryStream:
ms = new MemoryStream();
pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
byte[] photo_aray = ms.GetBuffer();

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_name", txtUserName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@father_name", txtFatherName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", txtPhone.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtEmail.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cnic", txtCNIC.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", txtAddress.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_type", txtType.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@workshop", txtWorkshop.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@department", txtDepartment.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@designation", txtDesignation.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emergency_no", txtEmergency.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", photo_aray);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The problem is that whenever I use an image field, I get the error

> Syntax error in insert into statement

If the image field is inserted without data it works like a charm though. I have also made a screenshot of the error.

[image]

Comment: What does your syntax error actually give you?

Comment: avoid inserting in database

Comment: Can you paste the actual error into your question please ?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7N0r.png you can see now

Comment: well im guessing it doesnt either like users and/or type

Comment: @BugFinder , cant understand what you saying

Comment: there are reserved words, Im sure type is one, I wouldnt be surprised if users is another

Comment: yes i know, but i think thats not the issue as its working without image

Comment: `type` is a [reserved word](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/286335/list-of-reserved-words-in-access-2002-and-in-later-versions-of-access) im MS Access `users` isn't.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please write out the text of errors you get in your message. This way search engines will have an easier time of directing people with the same problem to this thread. thanks!

Comment: @LonelyNeuron "Syntax error in insert into statement" this is my error

Comment: @MatSnow I change column type to user_type, still problem exist

Comment: On a side note you should call `ms.ToArray();` and not `ms.GetBuffer();`. See the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.getbuffer(v=vs.110).aspx), specifically the first paragraph of the Remarks.

Comment: What's the type of that image field in the database?

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth its ole object type iin database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Microsoft Access OLEDB provider considers `IMAGE` to be a reserved word in Access SQL so you need to enclose that column name in square brackets:

```
INSERT INTO ... emergency_no, [image]) VALUES ...
```

Comment: Thanks! that really help :)